# Is it safe to use Internet-facing RDP in combination with IP-whitelisting on Windows Firewall?

Tags: security, ip, rdp, whitelist

I am using a VPS that I connect to using RDP over the internet. Since I was experiencing an incessant stream of brute force attacks on the RDP, I configured the windows firewall to only allow certain IP-addresses to connect. This seems to work like a charm as the Failed Audit Log stays clean now. Yet I wonder if this practice is in fact secure.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple security controls are always better than one. Defense in depth.

Review [MITRE's index of remote desktop protocol](https://attack.mitre.org/techniques/T1021/001/) and its citations. Consider some of the ways to improve detection and mitigation.

- Audit users allowed to RDP
- Network segmentation (your firewall rules fall in this category)
- Bastion host, possibly using an implementation of remote desktop gateway protocol
- Multi-factor authentication
- Review login sessions